# How to redirect 301 CORS policy handle in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess, redirect

I am working on a project that uses api in angularjs.
I send http request to get user data and show on my html page
For example

```
www.example/users/get_user
```

This is working fine 
But now api call change and in this url they redirect 301 to another url like

```
from     
www.example/users/get_user to 301 
to 
www.example/api/users/user&page=0
```

But i can only send my request to the old url and that redirect me to new url

And Browser give me error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load
https://testing.twodegrees.io/profile/
user/logics.tester@gmail.com/images/
DF50D8BEE2CC11E6BFD706E21CB7534C--   -1.jpg. 
Redirect from 
  'https://testing.twodegrees.io/profile/user/logics.tester@gmail.com/
 images/DF50D8BEE2CC11E6BFD706E21CB7534C---1.jpg' 
 to 

'https://testing.twodegrees.io/uploads/
DF50D8BEE2CC11E6BFD706E21CB7534C--  -1.jpg' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: 
 Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow
 cross-origin   redirect.


    [enter image description here][1]
```

And i do not have access to .htaccess file
I have only front end that is in angularjs
thanks

Here is my code :

```
app.controller('testerCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    alert('heee');

    var image_name = 'DF50D8BEE2CC11E6BFD706E21CB7534C---1.jpg';
    var email = "logics.tester@gmail.com";

    if (image_name) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'https://testing.twodegrees.io/profile/user/' + email + '/images/' + image_name + '', true);
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-TWO_DEGREE-APP_ID", 'test_Anonymous_786');
        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            alert('this.response',this.response);
            console.log('this.response',this.response);
            var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(this.response);
            //   document.getElementById("text-area2").src = imageUrl;
            window.localStorage.setItem('current_chat_friend_img', imageUrl);
        }
        xhr.send();

    } 





}]);
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Can you please try adding `xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*'); xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` ?

Comment: Thanks @David R i have add this but still same error .Have you understand my problem???.I simple words  back-end team redirect  url 301 to another url